# Different results when date format is changed in mySql while comparing data

Tags: mysql, date, view

This is a query related to mysql. I have created a view using two tables... One of the fields in a table is "date", without any default value (i.e. null or dd-mm-yyyy or anything else). Now when I run a conditional query with [ date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-31' ], I get a different number of rows then the ones I get with [ date between '2012-1-1' and '2012-3-31' ].

One more important thing I see after using "desc viewName" is that it shows the default value for that date as '0000-00-00'.

If the query is as follow, I will get 120 rows :

```
select * from billing_master where date(pay_date) between '2012-1-1' and'2013-1-1';
```

If the query is as follow, I will get 45 rows :

```
select * from billing_master where date(pay_date) between '2012-01-01' and'2013-01-01';
```

Does anyone have an idea about it ?

Regards,
Sohil S.

Comment: What is the DataType of the pay_date field? Is it date?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pay_date field is of datatype DATE,

```
DATE_FORMAT(pay_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

if it is of type VARCHAR, etc. and you are just converting it to DATE per se

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE(pay_date),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Your Query should look like something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM billing_master  
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(pay_date),'%Y-%m-%d')  
BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-01-01';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... I tried using the query given by you with two different conditions i.e.  between '2012-01-01' and '2013-01-01' as well as between '2012-1-1' and '2013-1-1' and they showed different results... its really very strange...

Comment: have you tried searching if you have the values '2012-1-1'? MySQL stores date with leading zero's so I assume this has something to do with your values stored.

Comment: I checked the list of dates using select query and did not find any with '2012-1-1' i.e. without any leading zero...